# MVC2 404.4 error when trying to run project in iis7.5 (windows 7)

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, http-status-code-404

My problem is the following :

Create a new MVC2 application in visual studio 2010, right click the project and configure it to run using the local IIS web server.  Click on 'Create Virtual Directory' to create the directory in IIS.

So far so good, I then hit F5 to build and run the project and i get to the default page.

If i click on 'Logon' i get taken to the logon page

localhost/MyMVCApplication/Account/LogOn

If i click on the Log on button to POST my username and password I get the error

HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found - The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.

I can try it again with

localhost/RtculApplication/Account/Register

the GET request works fine, but the POST fails with the same error.

What am i missing? some configuration somewhere?

People with windows 7 iis7.5 visual studio 2010 can try this out, you should get the same issue?

I cannot find an answer to this anywhere on the web!

Comment: You probably can't find much info on it because most people prefer to use the built in webserver that comes with VS for testing. Is there some reason you've opted to use IIS?

Comment: I'm calling a web service and they both need to be hosted using the same port. That's why I want to run the site under iis

Answer (score 0):

Where is the project located in the file system? This can matter as IIS runs in a different context. If it is in the default place Visual Studio wants to store files, in your documents folder, IIS can have difficulties with file permissions. Best bet is to use a non-priviliged location -- eg. d:\projects\ -- as your default container for projects.

Comment: The site files are located on a d drive, I will check permissions but I dont see why this would be the cause of the problem. GETs work but POSTs don't?